# On variations of a claim due to Kaneko in terms of Lehmer means

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions

This post is cross posted from Mathematics Stack Exchange, due that there was a mistake from my part (see the excellent partial answer and my thread of edits of my question on MSE) this post on MathOverflow is slightly different of [*On variations of a claim due to Kaneko in terms of Lehmer means*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672588/on-variations-of-a-claim-due-to-kaneko-in-terms-of-lehmer-means) asked 30 days ago (May 13) as the question with identificator **3672588** of Mathematics Stack Exchange.

For a tuple of positive real numbers $\mathbb{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ we denote its corresponding Lehmer mean as $L_q(\mathbb{x})$, where $-1\lt q\lt 0$, I know the definition of these means from the corresponding Wikipedia with title [*Lehmer mean.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_mean).

Also we denote the sum of divisors function as $\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ for integers $n\geq 1$.

The idea of the post was to combine this definition of Lehmer mean with an equivalent formulation of the Riemann hypothesis, I refer the last paragraph of [1] (Kaneko's claim for a suitable choice of the integer $n_0$ from which the inequality in Kaneko's claim is true $\forall n\geq n_0$).

From here, my belief that there should be an integer $n_0>1$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0$ the following inequality holds $$\sigma(n)<\exp\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\log\left(\frac{n}{L_q(1,\ldots,n)}\right)\tag{1}$$
specifically for real numbers $-1\lt q\lt 0$.

**Fact.** *We've from the theory of Lehmer mean that we recover the inequality of Kaneko as* $q$ *tends to* $0^{-}$.

*Sketch of proof.* From the section of *Properties* and *Special cases* of the linked Wikipedia, and the continuity of a product of continuous functions (our exponential and logarithm).$\square$

> **Question.** I would like to know what work can be done to prove an inequality of the form $(1)$ for a specific value of $-1<q<0$, the least/smallest value of $|q|$ for which it is possible to prove that your inequality is true (I mean very close to $0$), and that holds $\forall n\geq n_0$ for a suitable choice of $n_0>1$ for your corresponding choice of a specific value of $-1<q<0$.
>
> **Many thanks.**

I emphasize that I'm asking **what work can be done** to prove an example for one of those inequalities $(1)$ for a very small quantity $|q|>0$ with $-1<q<0$ and that is true, our inequality, as a relaxation of Kaneko's claim for a segment of integers $n_0<n$. Feel free to add your feedback about if this type of inequalities (my interpretation of a relaxation or variation of Kaneko's claim) and combinations can be potentially interesting.

### References:

[1] Jeffrey C. Lagarias, *An Elementary Problem Equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis*, The American Mathematical Monthly, 109, No. 6 (2002), pp. 534-543.

[2] P. S. Bullen, *Handbook of Means and Their Inequalities*, Springer, (1987).

Comment: Feel free to add your feedback about the question, what I tried to evoke with my question (once I have noticed from the excellent partial answer of MSE the possible flaws in my statements) is try to prove an inequality $(1)$ similar than Kaneko's claim for suitable values of $-1<q<0$ and $n_0$, thus in my interpretation a relaxation, in some way, of the Riemann hypothesis. Many thanks for the attention and patience of users, and good day.

Comment: As aside comment (or companion/comparison reference for this MO post) I've also edited on Mathematics Stack Exchange the post with title *Around a weak form of the Riemann hypothesis inspired in the relationship between the Stolarsky means and the logarithmic mean*, that is the MSE question with identificator **3626466** (asked Apr 15) without an available answer (please if can with your MSE acount add your feedback in comments on the site MSE about the quesiton).